# How correct answer to appear when the user selects the wrong answer

Tags: flutter, dart, if-statement, colors

I want correct answer to displays when the user selects the wrong answer
In this code, it displays the wrong answer only and does not display the correct answer. How do I make the code display the wrong and correct answer to the user together?

```
Color getColorForOption(Answer answer) {
    bool correctAnswer = answer.isCorrect;
    bool isSelected = answer == selecetedAnswer;
    if (isSelected) {
        return correctAnswer ? Colors.green : Colors.red;
     } 
      return Colors.grey.shade300;
    }
```

[image]

I tried this code but it didn't work

```
Color getColorForOption(Answer answer) {
    bool correctAnswer = answer.isCorrect;
    bool isSelected = answer == selecetedAnswer;
    if (isSelected) {
      return correctAnswer ? Colors.green : Colors.red;
    } else if (correctAnswer) {
      return Colors.green;
    }
    return Colors.grey.shade300;
  }
```

Comment: Please add more code to edit into specific area.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the appropriate code for my question. Look at this code. Displays the correct answer with the wrong answer. If the user chooses the wrong answer, thank you.

```
Color getColorForOption(Answer answer) {
bool correctAnswer = answer.isCorrect;
bool isSelected = answer == selectedAnswer; 
if (isSelected) {
  return correctAnswer
      ? Colors.green
      : Colors.red; // Correct answer and selected
}
else if (!isSelected && correctAnswer && selectedAnswer != null) {
  return Colors.green; // Correct answer and not selected (show it when 
                          another option is selected)
} else {
  return Colors.grey.shade300; // Wrong answer and not selected
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

To achieve your aim, you have to approach the if-else statement in this manner.

```
Color getColorForOption(Answer answer) {
    bool correctAnswer = answer.isCorrect;
    bool isSelected = answer == selecetedAnswer;
    if (isSelected) {
        return correctAnswer ? Colors.green : Colors.red;
    } else {
        return correctAnswer ? Colors.green : Colors.grey.shade300;
    }
}
```

So when the option is not correct, the unselected color will be green while the selected will be red.

I already tested this and it worked.

Comment: Check out this gist: https://gist.github.com/kenresoft/48af1501b30acbf49e19944e6384fc18

Comment: There is a problem with this code as the correct answer appears before the answer

Comment: Can you further explain where the problem is.